# Google Maps Clusterer not displaying icons when cluster count > 1 digit

Tags: javascript, maps, markerclusterer

I am having an issue with Google Maps cluster function.  It is correctly clustering and placing cluster counts on the map and the cumulative counts total the correct number of locations/markers given it.  But no icons are showing when the count of the locations within a given cluster is greater than 9 (or greater than 1 digit count).  Does anyone have an idea how to correct this?  I am using the "standard" Google Maps blue icons for the clusters.  The blue icon shows for a cluster of 4 markers.  But the clusters of 132 and 79 markers only display the 132 and 79 counts -- no blue icons.  I don't have a convenient place to quickly put a screen capture for public consumption.

```
                            var tableContent = "";
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            iCount++;
                            var aCount = iCount.toString();
                            var iCt = item.RECNO;
                            //table += "<tr><td>" + '(' + aCount + ') ' + item.DDSPNM + "</td></tr>";
                            tableContent += '<tr>';
                            var rowContent = "";
                            rowContent += "<strong>" + item.DDSPNM + "</strong>" + "<br>"
                            rowContent += item.DCTRNUM;
                            tableContent += '<td>' + rowContent + '</td>';
                            tableContent += '</tr>';

                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);
                            locations.push(latlng);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng,
                                label: { text: aCount, color: 'black', fontSize: "12px" },
                                title: 'this is ' + item.DDSPNM,
                                map: map
                            });
                            gmarkers.push(marker);
                        });
                        if (iCount == 0)
                        {
                            table += "<tr><td>No providers were found in the specified location.  Please change your search criteria and try the search again.</td></tr>";
                            tableContent += "<tr><td>No providers were found in the specified location.  Please change your search criteria and try the search again.</td></tr>";
                        }
                        $('#results').append(tableContent);
                        // Instantiate pagination after data is available    
                        pager = new Pager('results', 10);
                        pager.init();
                        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');
                        pager.showPage(1);

                        //  set the bounds for the map and re-size/re-position to display all markers
                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                            bounds.extend(locations[i]);
                        }
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers,
                        { imagePath: @Url.Content("~/Images/m")});
                    }
```

Please ignore what is ugly presentation for the user, that's the piece I am working on now.  But I'm stumped as to why icons for clusters don't show when the count is greater than 9 (or greater than 1 digit).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for clogging up the works with this question.  All I can say is duh...I thought all of the icons were enabled in my VS project and that is wrong.  All I can say is that once I enabled all icons the yellows, reds, etc. starting appearing with multiple digit counts.

Sorry for personal screw up!